# Word for a time discrepancy in a story

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What is the word for the mistake of placing an event or object in the wrong age or decade, such as a film star in a movie about Roman times wearing a robe made of nylon?

Answer (score 15):

The word is *[anachronism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anachronism)*:

> **anachronism** The representation of someone as existing or something as happening in other than chronological, proper, or historical order.

To use it as an adjective or adverb, use *anachronistic* or *anachronistically*.

Comment: Not to be confused with *anarchism*... There's a song (supposedly based on true events) about how the FBI investigated the Society for Creative Anachronism, based on said word switch. The refrain of the song starts, "we're just harmless historical nuts."

Comment: @JPMiaou: Harmless, eh? It's the damned anachronists who wanted to replace the FBI's Glocks with crossbows and maces. And how would they fight crime then?

Comment: nice and quietly-like, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might mean anachronism.  (sp?)  I have too much cold medicine pumping through my bloodstream to know if I spelled it correctly.

Comment: Or to notice that Robusto posted the same thing five minutes before? It is spelled correctly, at least.

Comment: ...And get well soon!